# Query works on SQLite but fails on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, t-sql, join

The following query works for me in SQLite.

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id
            FROM Vehicles v
            WHERE v.Id = t.VehicleId) AS VehId
FROM Transactions t
WHERE t.VehicleId IS NOT NULL AND VehId IS NULL;
```

But in SQL Server, it gives me an error.

> Invalid column name 'VehId'.

And the editor puts a red squiggly line under the last `VehId` (but not the first).

As you might expect, `Vehicles.Id` is the primary key. I'm trying to find all foreign keys in `Transactions` that don't reference any row in `Vehicles`. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: This looks like a quirky anti-join to me. As a table's ID must never be null (otherwise it wouldn't be its ID), you can only get null, when `Transactions.VehicleId` has no match in the `Vehicles` table. But then you are looking for `VehicleId` only that are not null and IDs to another table should always have a foreign key to guarantee data consistency. So, you have a broken database and want to find invalid rows, yes? The typical way would be to use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` for such lookups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is that, in SQL Server, the column list is evaluated after the WHERE clause. That's why you can't reference a column alias from the WHERE clause.

There are several ways you can rewrite your query. Here are 3 of them.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Id, (SELECT Id
                FROM Vehicles v
                WHERE v.Id = t.VehicleId) AS VehId
    FROM Transactions t) x
WHERE VehicleId IS NOT NULL AND VehId IS NULL;

SELECT Id, VehId
FROM Transactions t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT Id
            FROM Vehicles v
            WHERE v.Id = t.VehicleId) v(VehId)
WHERE t.VehicleId IS NOT NULL AND VehId IS NULL;

SELECT Id, NULL AS VehId
FROM Transactions t
WHERE t.VehicleId IS NOT NULL 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id
            FROM Vehicles v
            WHERE v.Id = t.VehicleId);
```

Comment: This is not a "SQL Server" problem.  It is how the SQL language is defined.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: In all fairness to Luis Cazares, he didn't say it was a SQL Server problem. I think it's *my* problem that he's referring to.

Comment: @JonathanWood . . . "The problem is that in SQL Server, the column list is evaluated after the WHERE clause. "  The answer says it is a SQL Server problem.  It is not.  This is how SQL the language is defined.

Comment: No, I´m not saying that it's a problem of SQL Server. It's a problem with Jonathan's query that doesn't work with SQL Server's design.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: No one is questioning that is how the language was designed. I posted a question because I'm having a problem. He's saying my problem is due to how SQL Server is designed. He never said it's SQL Server's problem. I'm surprised you're sticking to your guns on this. Where did he say it was SQL Server's problem?

Comment: "The problem is that in SQL Server . . ." is the equivalent of "The problem you are experiencing come from the fact that in SQL Server . . ."

Comment: @avery_larry: Exactly.

Comment: I think your last examples makes the most sense to me.

Comment: @JonathanWood if you're learning SQL and want to continue learning, then I would like to suggest studying the "left join" solutions.  When I first started with SQL I wanted to stuff everything into the where clause but when I eventually got good with the various join solutions, I found that left joins combined with "where null" statements have generally had better performance over where clauses using "not in" or "not exists".  Take it or leave it.

Comment: @avery_larry: Actually, I might have been working with SQL longer than you have. But my focus has been on C# and C++, and most of my data access over the past decade has been using LINQ. So while I'm up for picking up new tricks, I'm not really looking to get deeper into it. I think I'm pretty comfortable with outer joins though, although I understand what you are saying about performance.

Comment: @avery_larry I've seen the opposite. IN and EXISTS use an operation called semi-join which is more efficient because it doesn't need to combine rows and affect the row count, it just checks for existence. Gail Shaw has a series of articles about that in [her blog](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/)

Comment: Intriguing, certainly.  I shall not doubt those who actually test over my experience.  Very likely my queries have other issues that, when combined with not in (I haven't tried not exists), perform much worse than left outer join and where is null.  I shall try not exists in the future.    Always learning.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to find records that don't match.

```
SELECT Id, v.Id AS VehId
FROM Transactions t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vehicles v ON v.Id = t.VehicleId
WHERE t.VehicleId IS NOT NULL AND v.Id IS NULL
```

This preserves the `VehId` column, but since you know that will always be `NULL`, then a similar set of data could be found with a sub-query. This would give you all the same rows, but missing the VehId column - you could always hard-code it, if you needed it for some reason.

```
SELECT Id
FROM Transactions t
WHERE t.VehicleId IS NOT NULL
AND t.VehicleId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Vehicles WHERE Id IS NOT NULL)
```

This would return you all transactions with an unknown (but not NULL) VehicleId

Comment: It's highly unlikely in this case, but `NOT IN` it can create problems if the subquery returns a NULL.

Comment: I thought that unlikely, since the `t.VehicleId IS NOT NULL`, but the subquery could also specify `WHERE Id IS NOT NULL`, I suppose.  (Added it, just in case)

Answer (score 2):

I think that your query can be simplified as a `LEFT JOIN` antipattern:

```
SELECT t.Id
FROM Transactions t
LEFT JOIN Vehicles v ON v.Id = t.VehicleId
WHERE t.VehicleId IS NOT NULL AND v.Id IS NULL
```

Another option is to use a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Transactions t
WHERE 
    t.VehicleId IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Vehicles v WHERE v.Id = t.VehicleId)
```

Comment: That's simpler, but it doesn't seem to do the same thing.

Comment: @JonathanWood: I just corrected my answer with 2 solutions

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference column aliases in where clauses which is why the query is failing.

Looking at it I think this might be what you are looking for, it essentially replicates a left join where the column in the right table does not match.

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id
            FROM Vehicles v
            WHERE v.Id = t.VehicleId and v.id is null) AS VehId
FROM Transactions t
WHERE t.VehicleId IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: `WHERE v.Id = t.VehicleId and v.Id is null` - Could that ever be true? How can `v.Id` equal `t.VehicleId`, *and* be null?

Comment: This query will not return the proper results.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your code worked, why would you want that 2nd column `VehId` in the results since it would be filled with `null`s?
Sure you can do a `LEFT` join or use another approach, but if you want to keep it simple like your code, remove that column from the `SELECT` list and move it to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t.Id 
FROM Transactions t
WHERE 
  t.VehicleId IS NOT NULL 
  AND 
  (SELECT v.Id FROM Vehicles v WHERE v.Id = t.VehicleId) IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is for troublshooting. I really don't care what columns are included as long as I can figure out which rows are broken.

Comment: I don't think it's because he wants the column, I think it's because that's how it was written in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Transactions t
WHERE t.VehicleId IS NOT NULL AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id
                  FROM Vehicles v
                  WHERE v.Id = t.VehicleId
                 );
```

Not only is this standard SQL, but it should have good performance on any database where `vehicles.id` is declared as the primary key.

Comment: I think this is the most straight forward approach for me. I've upvoted your answer, but Luis Cazares got the same one before you along with some other options so I've marked his as the accepted answer.